# google docs api - documentation shows how to 'dump' doc as JSON for troubleshooting, but JSON returned is different than JSON used to make requests

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm writing a google doc using the google docs api, and I found that there is a json 'dump' feature that helps you understand the structure of your google doc.

The only problem is, the JSON dump is different than the JSON used to actually write the doc.

For example, this is where I found out about the JSON dump:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/output-json

The  truncated JSON example looks like this:

```
{
    "body": {
        "content": [
            {
                "endIndex": 1, 
                "sectionBreak": {
                    "sectionStyle": {
                        "columnSeparatorStyle": "NONE", 
                        "contentDirection": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "endIndex": 75, 
                "paragraph": {
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "endIndex": 75, 
                            "startIndex": 1, 
                            "textRun": {
                                "content": "This is an ordinary paragraph. It is the first paragraph of the document.\n", 
                                "textStyle": {}
                            }
                        }
                    ], 
                    "paragraphStyle": {
                        "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT", 
                        "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT"
                    }
                }, 
                "startIndex": 1
            },
```

And here is documentation for making update requests to your document:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request

Basically what I'm seeing is that the two have some general structures in common, but the notation for actually writing the JSON is different.

For instance, here's an example of how to write to the document:

```
      const updateObject = {
        documentId: 'documentID',
        resource: {
          requests: [ {
            insertText: {
              text: 'hello world',
              location: {
                index: 1,
              },
            },
          } ],
        },
      };
```

I'm hoping there is a way I can write the json in the same way that the dump is structured, and then pass that format through to create new documents. Otherwise I'm going to have to tediously translate everything from one format to the other (and there's a lot),

Does anyone have any advice on this? Maybe there is something I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask on the issue [tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:555502%2B) I think you may get someone at google to answer that question.    Call it a feature request.  or a bug  I would think they should be the same.

Comment: thanks, it looks like someone asked a similar question on the issue tracker last year, not sure how to tell if anything is being done about it. I suppose I'll just get started translating ;0 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185013384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be intended. The JSON dump in the example matches the [Document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) object. You can also find this same structure returned when you create a document via the[`documents.create`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) API. Unfortunately, pretty much all of the fields are output-only. I tried to plug in the `body` from the sample into the API, and while it didn't fail, it also ignored the input and just created a basic document.

Meanwhile, the `batchUpdate` methods that you found to send update requests all seem focused on specific changes and none of them take a `Document` object. I think your best bet would be to follow up the feature request that you found, the Docs API is still considered in v1 after all.